# I'm having trouble trying to pass a variable into a complex regex that already works

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is some code I've been messing with  that basically takes a string containing HTML and removes elements with class="normal". To do so, the prototype function removes all line breaks, etc before it actually removes an element and all of its inner contents. The below code works as expected:

```
var msg = '<p>Keeping this paragraph</p>\n<p class="normal">Removing this paragraph<br>\n</p>\n<p class="normal">Another paragraph to remove<br>\n</p>';

String.prototype.takeOut = function() {   
    return this.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ")
           .replace(/<p[^>]*class="normal"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/g, '');
};

alert(msg.takeOut());
```

My problem is that I want to pass an argument through the method like so..

```
msg.takeOut('normal')
```

and let the prototype function take that argument to remove elements with whatever class we want like so:

```
msg.takeOut('foo')
msg.takeOut('bar')
```

Here is an example with more details:

http://jsfiddle.net/sc276v98/

I know that "new RegEx()" might be the solution, but how do I incorporate that into what already works? No jQuery please! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't manipulate HTML with regexp.

Comment: @torazaburo: What would you suggest to format a bunch of stuff?

I want to build an email template where there are different paragraphs but only some of them are included depending on what type of user it is sending to..

<p class="admin">Admin content here</p>
<p class="user">User content here</p>

As the emails are being sent out in the back-end, I need something that says "if its a user, remove admin stuff.. and vice-versa". 

Would I be better off not using classes and instead trying something like a square bracket shortcode? Ex:

[admin]admin stuff[/admin] 
[user]userstuff[/user].

Comment: I would use a templating system.

Comment: Ahhh ok.. I'm going to try jade with res.render(). I've gotta do this without a DOM as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [Mindastic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880380/mindastic) already has a working solution using Regex, this is just an alternative, using the nodes:

```js
var msg = '<p>Keeping this paragraph</p>\n<p class="normal">Removing this paragraph<br>\n</p>\n<p class="normal">Another paragraph to remove<br>\n</p>';

String.prototype.takeOut = function(x) {   
    var temp = document.createElement('div'), targets = temp.getElementsByClassName(x);
    temp.innerHTML = this;
    while(targets.length){ temp.removeChild(targets[0]); }
    return temp.innerHTML;
};

alert( msg.takeOut('normal') );
```

Comment: temp.innerHTML=this is a neat trick! This makes perfect sense. @torazburno's suggestion above is correct that I should probably use a template engine but I just need something quick and dirty that takes stuff out of existing html.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the jsfiddle code, try:

```
String.prototype.takeOut2 = function(i) {
  var regExp = new RegExp('<p[^>]*class="'+i+'"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>', 'g');
  return this.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ")
           .replace(regExp, '');
};
```

Comment: That's horrible. Who's going to maintain that?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. It does what I asked, but unfortunately, I didn't realize that the entire approach was bad technique!